# Formatting the data matched by a regular expression before updating a database

Tags: php, regex

I have a validation that accepts phone numbers in a specific manner and dumps them in a database but it does not convert them the way I want.

For example, if I enter `9999999999` or `09999999999` or `+919999999999` as a phone number, it gets into the database the way I have entered it.

How can I format it instead in the `+919999999999` style irrespective of how the user has entered it?

```
function validate_phone($input){
    $input = trim($input); //get rid of spaces at either end
    if (preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/',$input) == 1){
        return $input;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, you only need the last 10 digits to which you prepend the `+91` prefix.

We first make a small modification to the regex, adding parentheses around `[789]\d{9}` to capture it:

```
/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?([789]\d{9})$/
```

Then we use the third parameter of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to retrieve the capture, using the variable `$m`:

```
preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?([789]\d{9})$/', $input, $m)
```

The last 10 digits will be contained in `$m[2]`, we then return that prefixed with `+91`:

```
function validate_phone($input){
    $input = trim($input); //get rid of spaces at either end
    if (preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?([789]\d{9})$/', $input, $m) == 1){
        return '+91'.$m[2];
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
echo "\n".validate_phone('9999999999');
echo "\n".validate_phone('09999999999');
echo "\n".validate_phone('+919999999999');
```

Output:

```
+919999999999
+919999999999
+919999999999
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood the logic and the answer is correct. Just one more question. The user may enter an incorrect 10 digit number like 9999999999 8888888888 7777777777. 9898989898 etc. Can this be restricted by changing the regular expression? Is there a tough expression rule for phone numbers? Thanks

Comment: @Sabha I'm tempted to say that technically yes, although that really depends on the rules that govern the numbers. Depending on the complexity, this could really be its own question. Also regex is not always the answer either.

Comment: yup. thanks. I will post a seperate question for this to avoid only the numbers shown in my last comment.